# Creating a specific Turing Machine

Tags: state-machine, turing-machines

I am having some troubles with a exercise that asks to draw a Turing Machine which decides a language L2 = {w ∈ {0,1}∗|w contains an even number of 1’s }.

Does anybody have a solution to compare with what I have?

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've done, and someone might help you with that.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img907/4379/AhwGAe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design a turing machine that closely resembles this: [image]